# I need to change my success when my checkbox get unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".iCheck-helper" ).on( "click", function(){

        var sel = $('.i-check:checked').map(function(_, el) {
            // if($(this).is(":checked")){
                return $(el).val();
            }
        }).get();
        // alert(sel);

        var nme = $('.i-check:checked').map(function() {
            // return $(el).val();
            return $(this).attr("name");
        }).get();
        // alert(nme);

        var value = this.value;
        // this(attir)
        var city_name =<?php echo json_encode($cityname) ?>;
        var start =<?php echo json_encode($start)?>;
        var end =<?php echo json_encode($end)?>;
        var room_count =<?php echo json_encode($room_count)?>;
        var member_count =<?php echo json_encode($member_count)?>;
        var selt_guest =<?php echo json_encode($selt_guest)?>;
        var selt_room =<?php echo json_encode($selt_room)?>;
        // alert(city_name);
        $.ajax({
            // alert();
            type: "POST",
            url: "hotelresults",
            data: {
                key : sel,
                name:nme,
                search_city:city_name,
                start:start,
                end:end,
                selt_guest:selt_guest,
                selt_room:selt_room,
                room_nf:room_count,
                guest_nf:member_count,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.hotel_list').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

While clicking a checkbox this success function calls.And here `sel` & `name` are passed into the controller as in array manner.

If one of my checkbox is unchecked it should pass the remaining values of the array in both `sel` and `name`.

And if all the checkboxes are unchecked my `sel` & `name` value set to null.

So here,when my values get null or all checkboxes are set unchecked I need to pass another set of `data` in my `Success` like as follows.

```
data: {
    search_city:city_name,
    start:start,
    end:end,
    selt_guest:selt_guest,
    selt_room:selt_room,
    room_nf:room_count,
    guest_nf:member_count,
}
```

And here, I need that `.map` function as must because without that function my values didn't pass to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Here, rather than creating object directly in the Ajax call. Intiaite it first in a variable and assign that variable to data in call. Example below:

```
Var dataToSend = { search_city:city_name, start:start, end:end, selt_guest:selt_guest, selt_room:selt_room, room_nf:room_count, guest_nf:member_count}
```

Above are the properties which you need in every case.

Now check for optional ones as below:

```
If(nme && nme.length) {
    dataToSend.nme = nme;
}
```

And same for other variable.

In last. In the Ajax call, assign variable to data, like below:

```
data: dataToSend
```

Thanks,
Manish kumar